# Как передать json файл в шаблонизатор pug, ejs или любой другой где это возможно

Tags: node.js, gulp, pug, ejs

Код разбит на отдельные части, header, content, footer. Все эти части инклудятся в главный шаблон. У каждой части есть пул настроек, которые должны лежать в json файле. 
Как добавить в шаблон, например header.pug, переменную в которую будет загружен json файл, то есть:

```
- var settings= require('./settings.json');
```

К сожалению в pug это не работает. Какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

подключайте в роуте, перед рендером, и засовывайте в функцию render в data

```
const settings = require('./settings.json');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('template.ejs', {settings});
});
```

**UP:**

```
const pug = require('pug');
const settings_header = require('./settings_header.json');
const settings_content = require('./settings_content.json');
const settings_footer = require('./settings_footer.json');

pug.renderFile('/template.pug', {
    settings_header,
    settings_content,
    settings_footer
}, function (err, html) {
    // Ваш отредеренный шаблон
});
```

Comment: 1. У каждой части свой settings.js 
2. Как сделать это без express.js ?

Comment: @ИюльАвгуст Обновил ответ.